# Updating versionCode for Android PhoneGap app

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I have tried updating the *config.xml* file to include: versionCode="10002"

I've created a 'platforms/android/release-signing.properties' file and ran:

```
phonegap build --release android --versionCode=10002
```

Nothing seems to make the versionCode=10002 stick. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried it with both the "android-" prepended and without.
As well as with the parameters on separate lines rather than on the same line.

That did not help.

What did end up resolving it for me was creating a new PhoneGap Build app. That was created fine with the new version and I uploaded to the Google Play Store no problem. It seems to be a bug with PhoneGap's inability to update the version number. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you add `android-versionCode` instead of just `versionCode` to the `<widget>` in `config.xml`.

For example:

```
<widget id="com.test.app"
    version="1.2.3"
    android-versionCode="10002">
```